# flow_from_directory class_mode parameter

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was writing a CNN model to classify if the image had a forest, glacier, etc. Totally there were 6 classes. Hence the problem is of multi-class classification problems. I wanted to know what different values can the class_mode parameter of flow_from_directory have. Which value of them fits for this problem. 
My model output layer will have one node that outputs 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 denoting the class that the image belongs to.

Comment: This is something you can find in the Keras documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options are "categorical", "binary", "sparse", "input", or None.

What you need is sparse i.e. it will give you 1D integer labels.